# React Material UI Grid Item doesn`t render after data update

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm unable to make following code render grid items when `props.data` changes from the top component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import ProductCard from './ProductCard';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  grid: {
    padding: "8px",
  },
}));

export default function CenteredGrid(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const visibleProductData = props.data === null ? {} : props.data;
  return (
    <Grid container >
      {console.log("This is from the product card grid")}
      {console.log(visibleProductData)}
      {Object.entries(visibleProductData).map(productData => (
        <Grid key={productData[0]} className={classes.grid} item md={3} sm={6} xs={12}>
          <ProductCard data={productData[1]}/>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

When I run this, after the data updates, the console logs `visibleProductData` which is a dictionary consisting of three products, as expected. However these products are not visible, in fact when I inspect I see no children for Grid container. What is weird is that, even after small changes in code, when a fast refresh occurs products become visible. What might be the issue here ?

PS: I'm using `nextjs` along with `material ui`.

**Edit / Update - Parent Component**

```
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { buyer, categoryData, filterData, visibleProductData } = useContext(BuyerContext);

  if (!buyer) {
    return (
    <AuthRequired/>
  )} else {
    return (
      <>
        <HeaderBar/>
        <Grid className={classes.breadcrumb} container>
          <Breadcrumb />
        </Grid>
        <Divider variant="middle" />
        <main className={classes.main}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={2}>
              <Box display={{ xs: 'none', sm: 'block' }}>
                <CategoryList data={categoryData}/>
              </Box>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={10} xs={12}>
              <FilterGrid data={filterData}/>
              <ProductCardGrid data={visibleProductData}/>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </main>
        <Footer/>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line,

```
const visibleProductData = props.data === null ? {} : {...props.data};
```

It might be because your `visibleProductData` variable is always getting the same reference object. You need to create a new reference object each time `props.data` changes. If the issue still persists, then we need to see your parent component. The issue might be there.

Comment: Just tried this, still the same behaviour, I`ve posted an edit to the question including the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `const visibleProductData = props.data === null ? {} : props.data;` in React functional component body is not the correct "React way". You should:

1. define a local state variable called, for example, `visibleProductData`:

   `const [visibleProductData, setVisibleProductData] = useState({});`
2. use `useEffect` hook to "listen" new values comes from parent object. Something like:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      setVisibleProductData(props.data === null ? {} : {...props.data});
   }, [props.data]);
   ```

In this way, every time `props.data` changes, `useEffect` will be fired and it will update local `visibleProductData`.

Comment: Thanks, tried also this but still not working. This time at the initial load, component renders twice, I guess because of use effect, but at both renders it returns empty.

Comment: When I've changed ```{...props.data}``` to ```props.data```, at the second render, of useEffect it again got the data, but Grid items did not render.

Comment: And what if you put in your render something like `{props.data && <Grid container >...</Grid>}`?

Comment: If you mean, render conditionally, when the visibleProductData is null or empty just return null, and when there is data, render grid container and items, yes I did try that, and it`s not working either.

Answer (score 0):

I could at last solve the problem, it was a small typo that gives no error and therefore hard to debug. Instead of putting another "(" within map like so, `{array.map(element => (...))}` I should have done without it like this `{array.map(element => ...)}`.